# Good way to make a launcher screen for sub-apps within your app?

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app for a company, and they want a main screen when you first enter the app with a couple sub-apps (right now they're separate activities) that you can go into (glossary, faq, calculator, etc).

Any ideas what the best way to do this is? I'm new to all this.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "launcher screen"? Would just displaying a full screen bitmap for a second or two when an icon is touched (thereby acting as a splash screen) fulfill your needs? (note: this is terrible from a user interface design standpoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Gallery or a Grid, depending on the number of sub-apps we are talking about.

Example of Gallery: https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/com.ihaapp/ss-480-0-0

The grid view will look like the launcher app on your android phone.

Comment: initially its going to have about 3 sub-apps, could be more in the future though

Comment: @Jdban101: I think you should go with the Gallery view then. Try the app I linked to to get a feel for how that would work. https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ihaapp

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a case for the [Dashboard](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/dashboard-%E2%80%93-features) imho.

To implement this: Just lay out a few ImageViews or Buttons in a grid, and start the activitys inside the various onClick() events.

Comment: I made a grid a couple days ago and it looks like this: http://imgur.com/z4fiT IMO, pretty crappy, lol. I know it can look prettier, any suggestions? Right now its an Imageview grid

Comment: Hey, thats not what i meant. Check the link, theres a sketch and a few screenshots of some apps that use this type of layout, to see how it looks. If you have trouble implementing that, please open a new question with your attempt to build it. :)

Comment: Mh to make this prettier .. actually, if there are only 3 entries to put into, I'd personally would use the Gallery as suggested by videre. Away from that the whole thing needs some ui design of course, I'm afraid this would be way to much for an answer here (+ I'm not really a UI-designer).