# Help making a "launcher screen" for my app, and making it look right across devices

Tags: java, android

I posted a question here before: [Good way to make a launcher screen for sub-apps within your app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539578/good-way-to-make-a-launcher-screen-for-sub-apps-within-your-app), and then started working on other parts of the app, and now I'm back to the same thing.

I want to make a nice screen with icons that the user can press, with room for more icons at a later date. Or maybe something different, I'm not sure.

Here's a current screenshot of what it looks like:[image]

It looks pretty bad there, on my phone it looks better, with less space between the apps (this is a friend's phone), but ideally I want it to look good on all devices.

My XML code for this is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"   
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF6699FF"
    />
```

Any tips/suggestions are appreciated, I want to make this look good.
I'm not sure what format to store the icons in, right now they're just large (400x400 or so) png files.

Answer (score 1):

If your icons are just squares you might want to use a compressed format like jpg or gif to reduce your app's file size.

Comment: Good to know. The reason I have them so uncompressed is because they were looking crummy/blurry when put on the device.

Comment: ok about that it might be because of the screen density. Are you aware of ldpi mdpi hdpi etc?

Comment: Yes, I am. I had different ones sized for different resolutions, but I think the way this app is coded, they always have the same resolution? (refer to the XML)

I'm trying to get away from this so it looks better/the same on all devices, like the icons are the same "size" on the screen if the resolution is 400x800 or 200x600 or etc, like the same percentage of the screen.

Comment: Sorry, that last comment was supposed to be @Kevin Qiu, not sure what happened